# ggplot function for different data set by r

Tags: r

I would be more than thankful if you could help me, I need to write one code for the ggplot that works for the different data set, and that would be flexible
I want to run these codes by one code

```r
my_plot(mydata = airquality, subcol = "Month", subvalue = 9, 
        x = "Day", y = "Wind")
```

and this code

```r
my_plot(mydata = iris, subcol = "Species", subvalue = "setosa", 
        x = "Sepal.Length", y = "Sepal.Width")
```

I tried these codes but doesn't grab correct answers

```r
my_plot <- function(mydata,subcol,subvalue,x,y) {
  ggplot(data=mydata,aes_string(x,y)) +
    geom_point()
}
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What's not working?

Comment: I try to write a customized function code  that is flexible and works for plotting different data sets,

Comment: ```r                                                                                                        
  mydata=airquality
mydata=iris
my_plot<-function(mydata, subcol, subvalue ,my_function,my_method){
  ggplot(data=my_data,aes_string(x,y))+
    geom_point() 
}                                                                                                                                       ```                                                                                                                                            that I received errors

Comment: Please edit the question with your code and specify how it is failing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you almost have it.. Try this:

```
my_plot <- function(mydata,subcol,subvalue,x,y) {
  ggplot(mydata[mydata[[subcol]]==subvalue,],aes_string(x,y)) + geom_point()
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help but unfortunately that doesn't work, get error ,  Error in ggplot(mydata[mydata[[subcol]] == subvalue, ], aes_string(x,  : 
  could not find function "ggplot"

Comment: perhaps load the library (`library(ggplot2)`)

Comment: thank you but he ggplot2 was installed